# Can't have dhcp and static IP on the same interface

Tags: command-line, networking, dhcp, ifconfig

I'm having a problem. Can't set dhcp and static IP on the same interface at the same time.

My interfaces file:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface eth0:0 inet static
address 192.168.1.253
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I followed a tutorial but still no use. Only DHCP address is being displayed. I'm trying to make it without GUI.

Comment: Can you please share the link to the tutorial you followed with us?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're missing the following line:

```
auto lo eth0:0
```

**auto: the interface should be configured during boot time.**